# How to use gdal_translate to convert SHAPE to JPEG?

Tags: gdal

I am using [gdal_translate](http://gdal.org) command

```
$ gdal_translate.exe -of JPEG -outsize 2% 2% d:\rochester_bldg_region.shp d:\b.jpg
ERROR 4: `d:\rochester_bldg_region.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html), which burns vector geometries into a raster.

Note that this utility can't directly write JPEG files, so you will need to create a GeoTIFF, then convert that to JPEG.